# Find most meaningful variables on a dataset

Tags: matlab, correlation, data-analysis

Let's say I have a set of variables (vectors, all of them with the same length **N**): **X1,X2,X3,X4,X5,X6...Xn.** and a time series **Y** (with the same length **N**) that depend on some variables X .

I need an algorithm to determine which of the variables **X** are most correlated with **Y**. i.e I need to discard the least meaningful variables and get the MOST influential variables on **Y**.

Example:

Let's say we want to determine what influences the web traffic of a specific IT site. And we have 5 keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, and keyword5.

Let's say we have the keywords' search volume on Google **(key1= X1,key2= X2,key3=X3,key4=X4,key5=X5)**, and the total web traffic **Y**. I want to determine what keywords from the set above (X1,X2,X3,X4, or X5) are most meaningful to the total web traffic to that website. Which variables I can discard and which ones move the most traffic. (Let's say all these vectors and the time series are normalized and standardized time series)

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "meaningfulness". There are different measures you can use. Are you looking for causality here? And are the variables numeric or categorical or ordinal?

Comment: Numeric. Between 0 and 100. And I suppose I am looking for linear correlation.